# How to check if Ubuntu is still installed? (Windows Vista)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-vista

I have recently gotten back a laptop I lent to a friend, who had lent it to someone else, and so on, and so forth, for the last 8 years. When I handed it over I had installed Ubuntu (dual boot) and from what I can remember it was quite easy to choose Ubuntu to boot from but now I can't find the option anywhere. It is quite possible that someone removed it to save space. How do I check if it is still there?

Comment: @muclux I suggest writing that up as answer, I would upvote it :p

Answer (score 1):

You could boot with an Ubuntu live system (from USB or DVD) and type `lsblk -f` in a terminal. If there are still partitions formatted as ext3 your ubuntu is probably still there. Then you can try the boot repair options.

Comment: Thanks! What I get when I type this in is something like: sda -sda1 -sda2, sdb -sdb1 /cdrom, loop0 /rofs. Does this mean Ubuntu is gone?

Comment: Did you use the option `-f` in `lsblk -f`? Then you should get more. For a better readability please copy/paste the command and its output into your question, mark it and click on '{}'.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                 
├─sda1              
└─sda2              
sdb                 
└─sdb1              /cdrom
loop0               /rofs

Comment: Didnt understand where to click on curly brackets

Comment: The curly brackets are above the editor field when you are editing your question.

Comment: Your output doesn't show any filesystem type at all, so I suppose you have only unformatted partitions. Normally you would see something like `├─sda7  ext4              3fbf407e-3505-42c7-82a7-7aceef817bcc /`, showing the filesystem type at the second position of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the size of your Hard drive to the amount of space taken up by windows will give you a clue. If you are unable to find it in a boot menu then more than likely it is lost unless you go through data recovery steps which can be very tricky and ultimately fruitless.

If the space on hard drive vs space taken up by windows is large enough (above about 8 gigs) to indicate that there might be another OS installed you need to check in Windows and see what that "open space" is formatted as or if it is unformatted.

I suspect you won't need to go that far, if they removed it then the space should be taken up by windows.